# Associative array - change position

Tags: php

For ex have this array:

```
[food] => Array (
    [fruits] => apple
    [vegetables] => garlic
    [nuts] => cashew
    [meat] => beaf
)
```

I need to change the position of a specific key-value combination.

Let's say I need to move  [fruits] => apple to 3rd position

```
[food] => Array (
    [vegetables] => garlic
    [nuts] => cashew
    [fruits] => apple
    [meat] => beaf
)
```

I am not talking about sorting by key or value.
I need to change position of key-value to a very strict new position.

Something like:

```
change_pos($my_arr, $key_to_move, $new_index);
```

=>

```
change_pos($my_arr, "fruits", 3);
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was hard , but finally:

```
<?php
function array_splice_assoc(&$input, $offset, $length, $replacement) {
        $replacement = (array) $replacement;
        $key_indices = array_flip(array_keys($input));
        if (isset($input[$offset]) && is_string($offset)) {
                $offset = $key_indices[$offset];
        }
        if (isset($input[$length]) && is_string($length)) {
                $length = $key_indices[$length] - $offset;
        }

        $input = array_slice($input, 0, $offset, TRUE)
                + $replacement
                + array_slice($input, $offset + $length, NULL, TRUE);
}
function array_move($which, $where, $array)
{
    $tmpWhich = $which;
    $j=0;
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
    {
        if($keys[$i]==$tmpWhich)
            $tmpWhich = $j;
        else
            $j++;
    }
    $tmp  = array_splice($array, $tmpWhich, 1);
    array_splice_assoc($array, $where, 0, $tmp);
    return $array;
}
$array = array('fruits' => 'apple','vegetables' => 'garlic','nuts' => 'cashew','meat' => 'beaf');
$res = array_move('vegetables',2,$array);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

Comment: is that work for none numeric index?? can you provide demo example using http://phpfiddle.org

Comment: this don't work correctly, don't move the index of others elements

Comment: @MIIB: you posted an answer to my question, why you deleted it, please post it again, it looks very good...

Comment: Oh you know, the problem to my answer was that function move the element with its key, but i saw that you only want to move the value and not the key.

Comment: thank you! sorry I didn't have a chance to try the code. As soon as I try I will accept the answer. Thanks for efforts!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to thank MIIB for his hard work! I will accept his answer for the hard work.

But I came up with a solution that fits me better and I will use it.

```
function ksort_arr (&$arr, $index_arr) {
    $arr_t=array();
    foreach($index_arr as $i=>$v) {
        foreach($arr as $k=>$b) {
            if ($k==$v) $arr_t[$k]=$b;
        }
    }
    $arr=$arr_t;
}

$arr=array("fruits"=>"apple","vegetables"=>"garlic","nuts"=>"cashew","meat"=>"beaf");
$index_arr=array("vegetables","meat","fruits","nuts");
ksort_arr($arr,$index_arr);
print_r($arr);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [vegetables] => garlic
    [meat] => beaf
    [fruits] => apple
    [nuts] => cashew
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much simpler solution using a second array. It also provides some basic validation for new index parameter. Intended to be used with associative arrays only. It does not make sense to be used with numeric arrays.

```
function array_move($key, $new_index, $array)
{
    if($new_index < 0) return;
    if($new_index >= count($array)) return;
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $array)) return;

    $ret = array();
    $ind = 0;
    foreach($array as $k => $v)
    {
      if($new_index == $ind)
      {
        $ret[$key] = $array[$key];
        $ind++;
      }
      if($k != $key)
      {
        $ret[$k] = $v;
        $ind++;
      }
    }
    // one last check for end indexes
    if($new_index == $ind)
        $ret[$key] = $array[$key];


    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
/**
 * Moves an array item to a new index .
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @param int $from
 * @param int $to
 * @return void
 */
function array_move(array &$array, int $from, int $to)
{
    $item = array_splice($array, $from, 1);
    array_splice($array, $to, 0, $item);
}

/**
 * Moves an associative array item to a new index.
 * 
 * @param array $array
 * @param string $key
 * @param int $to
 * @return void
 */
function array_move_assoc(array &$array, string $key, int $to)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $array)) return;

    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $values = array_values($array);
    $from = array_search($key, $keys);

    array_move($keys, $from, $to);
    array_move($values, $from, $to);

    $array = [];
    foreach ($keys as $index => $key) {
        $array[$key] = $values[$index];
    }
}
```

```php
$array = [
    "fruits" => "apple",
    "vegetables" => "garlic", 
    "nuts" => "cashew", 
    "meat" => "beaf"
];

array_move_assoc($array, "fruits", 2);
print_r($array);
```

```
Array
(
    [vegetables] => garlic
    [nuts] => cashew
    [fruits] => apple
    [meat] => beaf
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).